# Is having 22 segues to 1 Viewcontroller a bad thing when I use static and grouped cells?

Tags: iphone, ios

Ok so I honestly don't think it is good practice but at the moment I don't really see another good solution for this.
Then I will apply an if else statement in prepareforsegue where for 22 times it will be checked which segue was used so the correct data is displayed in the second viewcontroller.
Is this bad practice or not?

Comment: why do you need 22 different segues? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It seems like bad practice. There is probably some abstraction that could solve this problem...

Comment: You're right about it being bad practice. The question is though, what is "for this" -- what are you trying to do? If you have 22 static cells, you might consider switching to dynamic ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can use just one segue and pass the data to the second view controller inside your if/else.

You could have a property on your second view controller and, on your `prepareForSegue` method on the first view controller, you can set the data that you want to send.

Example:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ExampleSegueIdentifier"])
    {
        SecondViewController *secondView = (SecondViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];

        // assuming that we want to fill a NSString on the Second View Controller
        secondView.myText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello, World"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Or just present it modally programatically.  This is why I dislike segues.

Comment: How do i check here which cell was tapped? indexpath.row doesn't really work here?

Comment: you can check which cell was tapped inside your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.. there, you can call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ExampleSegueIdentifier" sender:nil];`.. this will bring the code execution to here.

Comment: Jip that was what I discovered a few hours ago :p So it works now.

Comment: working with segues is like following a 'cooking recipe'.. write those steps on some post-its and glue it around your desktop and you will always be ok.. :).. it is just a matter of getting used to it.. I hope that I've helped you

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want. If you want to display certain data depending on which `UITableViewCell` was pressed, all you have to do is have a table view on view 1, on view two, have some blank UILabels (or whatever you would like to use to present the data), And load the data into the UI objects (UILabels, etc) depending on which cell was pressed. A very good tutorial of this is located [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QBrkavVJsw0). This tutorial shows how to do this as well as saving the data, you might not need to save any data, so take away what you can about loading data into views from table view cells. Yes, what you are doing is kind of a bad practice, although it totally depends on what you want to do.

HTH :)

Comment: Not to be harsh but there isn't even a storyboard on 1 of his 3 tutorials :p

Comment: The tutorial was to help you with grasping the idea of how to pass data to different views, which is what i thought you were having trouble with. You can implement the storyboard yourself.